# Flashing Cyanogenmod hltevzw to Note 3

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm a bit confused with Cyanogenmod's announcement stating that they are breaking up the Note 3 builds into their own version. [Source](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/psa-note-3-devices-and-variants-update)

Is the hltevzw a build specifically for the Note 3 or all Verizon phones? I just want to be sure before flashing the wrong rom.

Has anyone else flashed the hltevzw to their Note 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the hltevzw a build specifically for the Note 3 or all Verizon
>   phones? I just want to be sure before flashing the wrong rom.

It's for the Verizon Note 3 only.